# .txt limit, need help

Tags: java, overflow, text-files

I have a problem here and no idea what to do. Basically I'm creating a .txt file which serves as an index for a random access file. In it I have the number of bytes required to seek to each entry in the file.

The file has 1484 records. This is where I have my problem: with the large amount of bytes the record has, I end up writing pretty long numbers into the file, and ultimately the .txt file ends up being too big. When I open it with an appropriate piece of software (such as notepad) the file is simply cut off at a certain point.

I tried to minimize it as much as possible, but it's just too big.

What can I do here? I'm clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: is the problem that the textfile is too big for Notepad or just too big in general?

Comment: I have a text/CSV file with almost 10 million records. I can assure that Java can handle larger text files. ;)

Comment: The problem is likely the statement "When I open it with an appropriate piece of software (such as notepad)" is not correct. Notepad is usually never appropriate except for the most trivial of tasks. I suggest finding a better "notepad" such as notepad++, editplus, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure that the problem is that one... only 1484 records?

You can write a binary file instead, in which each four or eight bytes correspond to a record position. This way, all positions have the same length on disk, no matter how many digits they hold. If you need to browse/modify the file, you can easily write utility programs that decode the file so it lets you inspect it, and that encode your modifications, modifying it.

Another solution would be to compress the file. You can use the zip capabilities of Java, and unzip the file before using it, and zip it again after that.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are not feeding new lines to terminate each line. There is a limit set to the maximum line length that text editors can handle safely.

Answer (score 0):

Storing your indices in a binary file, inside some kind of Collection (depending on your needs) would probably be much faster and lighter.